# MySQL Query Speed Joins

Tags: mysql, performance, join

Are there any ways that the following query could be optimised for speed? It takes about 6 seconds to execute. Each table only contains around 1000 records so it's not huge.

```
SELECT c. * , q.qualification_name, CONCAT( u.firstname, ' ', u.lastname ) AS name, v.venue_name, v.address_town
FROM p_courses c
LEFT JOIN p_qualifications q ON c.qualification_name = q.ref
LEFT JOIN p_users u ON c.instructor_number = u.instructor_number
LEFT JOIN p_venues v ON c.venue_token = v.token
WHERE (
c.status = 'completed'
OR c.status = 'confirmed'
)
```

The above query works and retrieves all data as requested, it just takes a long time as soon as I add more than one LEFT JOIN.

Thanks.

EDITED.

Adding EXPLAIN in front of the query returns this...

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key   key_len   ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      c       ALL     NULL            NULL  NULL      NULL    1288    Using where
1   SIMPLE      q       ALL     NULL            NULL  NULL      NULL    21   
1   SIMPLE      u       ALL     NULL            NULL  NULL      NULL    518  
1   SIMPLE      v       ALL     NULL            NULL  NULL      NULL    669
```

Sorry but I'm not quite sure how to interpret that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. check what's wrong by putting `EXPLAIN` in front of your query.
2. set your indeces so your joins and your where can use them.
3. check you `EXPLAIN` again
4. lather, rinse, repeat.

hints: you probably want an index on:

```
c.qualification_name 
q.ref
c.instructor_number 
u.instructor_number
c.venue_token 
v.token
c.status
```

Comment: You should edit that in your question, fix the formatting there, but most of all, check it and look what you can figure out from it. As I said, you need indices on the fields you're joining on// performing a where on, so add the indices, and see if it helps. Don't just dump one explain, try what I suggested :)

Comment: Formatting fixed. So it seems like I need to add indexes on those fields.

Comment: It says: possible keys: NULL. again. ADD KEYS. look up how to add keys to your table. I'll give you a hint above, but you need to put in some effort yourself too :)

Comment: Bingo! I added indexes on q.ref, u.instructor and v.token (the references used in JOIN) and now it's lightning fast!!!

Answer (score 0):

From the Explain you posted it doesn't look like the query is using indexes. Ensure that q.ref, u.instructor_number and v.token are indexed